# Python Application Breaks From While Loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm creating a little Python program to kill programs that use idle bandwidth while I'm playing games. I have encountered a little problem, That problem being that my app breaks from its loop. I'm not very good in python so if you can help me understand why this happens I would be most grateful.

```
while commandStage == 0:
    command = input("Enter a command : ")
    commandStage = commandStage + 1
if "stopbits" in command:
(os.system("taskkill svchost.exe -k netsvcs"))
commandStage = commandStage - 1
```

My theory behind this is that while `commandStage` is 0 it will wait for a command and when it has received a command it will carry out that command and go back to the while loop but it doesn't which is why I need help.

Comment: @N. Wyatt: your indentation is incorrect. You have an empty `if` block, which is invalid python syntax.

Comment: Once you get out of the while loop, you are not going to get back in again. This is not a Python issue, this is general programming, the code gets executed line by line, and when you reach the end it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1 run you have done

```
commandStage = commandStage + 1
```

And

```
while commandStage == 0:
```

Is no longer run.

*EDIT for comment* The commandStage-1 is done outside the while, you need to indent it if you want the if and -1 done inside the loop.

Based on the full comment I guess this might just be what you are trying to do

```
while commandStage == 0:
  command = input("Enter a command : ")
  commandStage = commandStage + 1
  if "stopbits" in command:
    (os.system("taskkill svchost.exe -k netsvcs"))
  commandStage = commandStage - 1
```

But see other answer for a better way of just making endless loop (while true:)

Comment: I can't understand what you're exactly trying to say. But I think you're forgetting I'm using `commandStage = commandStage - 1` to try and return it back to the loop.

Comment: I understand now, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use an infinite while loop and move your condition into the loop and break out of the loop if the condition is not met

```
while True:
    command = input("Enter a command : ")
    if "stopbits" in command:
        (os.system("taskkill svchost.exe -k netsvcs"))
    else:
        break
```

Take a look at this http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to do is:

```
while True:
    command = input("Enter a command : ")
    if "stopbits" in command:
        os.system("taskkill svchost.exe -k netsvcs")
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped into `ipython` to show you how this works:

What happens is that the value that is received from `input(...)` is a string, which any non-empty string returns `True` if tested for truthiness which means that the loop exits right away.

This example shows what is happening.

```
In [1]: test = input("Enter >>")
Enter >> hi

In [2]: type(test)
Out[2]: str

In [3]: bool(test)
Out[3]: True
```

What you want to do is wrap the output of `input` with an `int( )`. But if you are entering more than integers you will come across problems and should probably do some `try: ... catch: ...` statements rather than just breaking.

Feel free to comment with follow up questions below and I'll help! Or hit me up on Twitter - [@dalanmiller](https://twitter.com/dalanmiller)